# Jitsi Meet in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, jitsi-meet

How can we use Jitsi Meet in Flutter? I need to add Jitsi meet to my current application, but it seems there is no any proper example to use jitsi in flutter application.
I would appreciate a lot if someone can provide me some example or reference to it. Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `jitsi_meet package` for flutter.
jitsi_meet package link: https://pub.dev/packages/jitsi_meet
Follow the instruction of the package.

Answer (score 0):

You should try one of the following (I was able to implement it successfully by following the Official GitHub Repo):

[Official GitHub Repo](https://github.com/gunschu/jitsi_meet/tree/master/jitsi_meet)

[article by Rishabh Sharma](https://medium.com/flutter-clan/free-video-conferencing-app-built-on-flutter-62123eddd6e7)

[article by Akshay Maurya](https://codenameakshay.medium.com/implementing-video-meets-in-flutter-using-jitsi-meet-5426ca37810a)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).